# Empty tag wiki shows some text in the edit window

Tags: support, edits, tag-wiki

When editing tag wiki for [thread-dump](/questions/tagged/thread-dump), I have noticed that there is already **some text pre-filled in the edit window** for that wiki. See [Wiki for thread-dump tag - edit window](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/14693).

But, this tag does not have any wiki yet and I do not remember filling in this text.

**Q**: Could it be a rejected wiki edit from some other user?

**Q**: Can you see it too? It this a bug or a feature?

I will edit the tag wiki anyway but I was just wondering where did this text come from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because the tag already has a tag wiki. The [wiki got approved](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/361678) and the [excerpt got rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/361679) when the first user edited it. Tag wikis are only displayed when the tag *also* has an excerpt. If it doesn't have an excerpt but has a wiki, nothing is displayed. If it doesn't have a wiki but has an excerpt, the excerpt is displayed with no tag wiki.

Once an excerpt is added, the wiki will be displayed correctly on the info page.